# Find the expected value of X given other moments

Tags: self-study, variance, random-variable, expected-value, moments

Given the variance $\mathbb{V}(X)=7$ and the expected square $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=16$, what is the expected value of $X$?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hint: there are *two* correct answers.

Comment: @whuber: That might be my fault --- I heavily edited the original question for clarity and notation.  I recall that it may have specified that it was looking for a positive expected value, and it looks like I accidentally omitted that part in my edit.  Anyway, I think the user now has enough hints to assist.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** The [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition) of $X$ can be written as $\mathbb{V}(X) = \mathbb{E}(X^2) - \mathbb{E}(X)^2$.